# Error: Unexpected value 'FileExportService' declared by the module 'LayoutModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project app.module.ts is main module and layout.module.ts is child module.
The interesting thing about this error is that when I build with command *ng build --prod --aot* and also just *ng build* It is working fine on localhost there is no any error.But whenever we deploy in server with java backend .It starts showing this error.. 
And I have used lazyloading...

**my app.module.ts**

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
        import { DatePipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
        import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
        import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
        import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
        import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { FileExportService } from './shared';

        @NgModule({
        declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientXsrfModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedPipesModule,

        NgxPermissionsModule.forChild(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [Http]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        FileExportService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TfmHttpInterceptorService,
            multi: true,
        }
      ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**my layout.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, QuickaccessComponent } from '../shared';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/modules/shared.module';
import { jqxMenuComponent } from 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxmenu';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        LayoutRoutingModule,
        TranslateModule,
        TreeModule,
        SharedModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        QuickaccessComponent,
        jqxMenuComponent,
    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    entryComponents:[
        QuickaccessComponent,
    ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

**And my package.json is**

```
{
    "name": "my-data-processing-system",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --ec true --port 4201",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "gitbuild": "ng build --prod --base /start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/master/dist/",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
        "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.1",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
        "core-js": "^2.5.3",
        "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jqwidgets-framework": "^5.6.0",
        "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
        "ng-pdf-make": "0.0.2",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ngx-permissions": "^3.2.2",
        "pdfmake": "^0.1.35",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
        "xlsx": "^0.11.19",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.1",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.101",
        "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "^1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
        "tslint": "~5.3.2",
        "typescript": "~2.5.2"
    }
}
```

**my file-export.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { utils, write, WorkBook } from 'xlsx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Injectable()
export class FileExportService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe,private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }
  SaveFile(data,fileName){
    saveAs(data,fileName);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code for the service

Comment: I have added my service @AluanHaddad

Comment: The error indicates that you're using declarations instead of providers to register the service. That would be the error

Comment: No ,Look at app.module.ts  I have used as provider to register the service. And my layout module is the child module we don't need to declare in it.@AluanHaddad

Comment: is it possible that you've also registered it somewhere else? I understand that the error is not present in the code you've posted

Comment: I have checked each and every line .There is no error .when running ng serve it does not show any error .I have also built in prod mode made run in local server. There is also no error it's working.But Whenever I try to deploy with java backend it shows error.What may be the reason?@AluanHaddad

Comment: that's very odd. It definitely has nothing to do with Java but it could have something to do with how your bundling the application for deployment. Make sure that your language, module loader or bundler, and angular versions are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

In my project `app.module.ts` is main module and `layout.module.ts` is child module.

1. Because your Layout Module is the child module, please add this module inside of your app.module.ts:

   ```
   import { LayoutModule } from 'path to your LayoutModule';
   ...
   @NgModule({
   imports: [
       ..., 
       LayoutModule 
   ]
   ```
2. Export the component(s) from your `layout.module.ts`:

   ```
   ...
   entryComponents:[
        QuickaccessComponent,
   ],
   schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
   exports: [                         // Here
       LayoutComponent,
       HeaderComponent,
       SidebarComponent,
       QuickaccessComponent,
       jqxMenuComponent,
   ]
   ```

And THIS:

> Unexpected value **FileExportService** declared by the module **LayoutModule**'

So some questions remain:

- I don't see any `FileExportService` in your `LayoutModule` anywhere in provider, so this might be the problem?
- Please add this `FileExportService` into your **provier** in `LayoutModule` @ngModule if it solved it.

I hope this helps :)